# select the rows where is greater than a certain number using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

wanted excel file should be like: [image: main excel file] main excel file is :[image: wanted excel be like :]have an excel file and i want to select the rows where is greater than a number.

and i want my output be like the image
**i want make an new excel file where that the "R"s are greater than 130, and returns the "SN"s for those specified "R" s**
i wrote a code but it did give me only true , false values , not the cell

```
    v=int(input("how many periods do you have:\n"))
    new_excel_by_user=str(input("write the name of your new EXCEL file:"))
    user_excel = pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    sys_excel=pd.ExcelWriter('sys_excel132.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    final_excel=pd.ExcelWriter('final132.xlsx' , engine='xlsxwriter')


    merged_df_H = pd.DataFrame()
    merged_df_L = pd.DataFrame()
    final_merged=pd.DataFrame()


    for i in range(v):
    print("\npriod %d :"%(i+1))

   excelpathH=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(HIGH):")
   excelpathL=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(LOW):")
   excelpathH=excelpathH.replace('"', '')
   excelpathL=excelpathL.replace('"', '')
   dfH=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl' )
   dfL=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathL), engine='openpyxl' )

   Rnh=dfH['KPIVALUE']
   Rnl=dfL['KPIVALUE']
   R=Rnh-Rnl
   merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)]=R
   R=merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)]
   #the below code returns true false only
   RESULT=merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)].ge(130)
   print(".....................................................................")



   merged_df_H = pd.concat([ merged_df_H,dfH,dfL,R,RESULT], axis=1 )

   final_merged=pd.concat([final_merged,dfH['SN'], R,RESULT],axis=1)
```

Comment: If you can convert it to Datafram, try this ,df is a dataframe,
df2=df[df["COLUMN_NAME"]>value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same index in `dfH` and `R` DataFrames is possible use:

```
mask = merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)].ge(130)

merged_df_H = pd.concat([merged_df_H,
                         dfH.loc[mask, 'SN'].reset_index(drop=True),
                         R[mask].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Also is better avoid duplicated `SN` columns, you can `rename` it:

```
merged_df_H = pd.concat([merged_df_H,
                         dfH.loc[mask, 'SN'].rename('SN%s'%(i+1)).reset_index(drop=True),
                         R[mask].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: it worked but with a certain problem.......... for exmple  SN3 has value greater than 130, but it returns it as SN1 not SN3

Comment: PLEASE CHECK THE IMAGES,

Comment: @SOURAELLE - Where are `SN` columns? In `merged_df_H` ?

Comment: YES,  they are in merged_df_H

Comment: @SOURAELLE - Are `SN` columns before `R`s columns? Are no columns between `SN` and `R` columns?

Comment: yes, SN columns are before R  column, at the beginig of the cod itt asks from user that how many "R"s do you have, and according to the users answer it adds "SN" and "R" columns in each FOR  loop

Comment: @SOURAELLE - What code add `SN` columns? I cannot see it in your code.

Comment: merged_df_H = pd.concat([ merged_df_H,dfH,dfL,RESULT], axis=1 )
    
final_merged=pd.concat([final_merged,dfH['SN'],RESULT],axis=1)

Comment: @SOURAELLE - So `SN` columns are not in `merged_df_H` ?

Comment: im sorry, your right , they were in another excel file that has a dataframre name "dfH"